# How to embed vertically responsive player?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, jwplayer

Hello everyone i want to make my player responsive on both side horizontal and vertical i am using jwplayer by searching and reading problems on stackoverflow i have make my player responsive
This is my website http://watchers.to/embed-2yn20c1qpcv1.html

i am using JW player i make it responsive but its working only on horizontal i want to make responsive like this website http://thevideo.me/embed-hvmn6i17xvsd.html

please help what should i do